# How can I have Linux Mint 15 Olivia always startup in console mode

Tags: linux-mint

Several months ago, I installed Mint 15 on an old laptop with the intent to use it to run various game servers for the house. All of these are console apps, so I'd like to not have to bother booting into any GUI. I just have no idea how to achieve this, or if it is any different from how this is achieved with other Linux flavours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

find the line which now says  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”`

and revise it to read  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash text”`

then run `sudo update-grub`

Your next boot will bring you to the command line interface (CLI).